# How to decode a token with jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jwt

When I try to verify the token of user, I always get the Error 500.

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
if(!req.headers.authorization){
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
}
let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
if (token === 'null') {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
}
let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretkey')
if (!payload) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
}
req.userId = payload.subject
next()
```

I started by surround with a try catch the payload, I think I understand that jwt operation had changed and that it now needs this to work, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. It seems he can't check the match.

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
if(!req.headers.authorization){
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
}
let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
if (token === 'null') {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
}
try {
    let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretkey')
    req.userId = payload.subject
    next()
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [jwt-decode](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) /[npm jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) library to decode. Example from doc:

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

var token = 'eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token';
var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
console.log(decoded);
```

other library to check [angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt)

Comment: I change the "let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretkey')" by "let payload = jwt_decode(token)" and now it work, thank you ! but how jwt_decode know the key to decode the token ?? it is not mentioned anywhere

Comment: payload of jwt is encoded in base64 - to shorten a long string. You can try out in https://jwt.io